# Vectorising lines appear as a mixture of bubbles and lines from raster map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, arcscan

I have these road raster maps which I have reclassified into binary images to try and vectorise. However, when I click on vectorise and generate feature, it comes out as a mixture of bubbles and lines (see screenshots). I tried to play around with the vectorsing settings but without much success. I would like to just get a line following the roads.

[image: basically the road network is the black bits inside the red bubbles and lines]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like using automatic vectorization you are getting a mixture of polygons (bubbles) and the polylines you desire. Try using the [Raster to Polyline](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polyline.htm#GUID-0ADBDD34-5554-43C5-A91C-CF2BCD4E4287) tool to force your output to be only polylines.

Just as a note, if you can give further details about what you've tried (ex. what are the exact tool(s) you are using, or which settings you have tried changing) it will make it easier for people to help you.